# How can i disconnect Google Actions from my project without deleting the whole project?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-console

I want to remove [Google Actions](https://console.actions.google.com/) from my project. But if i understood correctly, pressing delete project removes the whole project, including all Firebase and Analytics data linked to it. How can i avoid that?
[image]

This is what [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/console/manage) says about that, however it doesn't help.

I didn't dare to press delete without knowing for sure, since what i read from the internet indicates that it deletes the whole project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further checking, once linked, these cannot be decoupled as it is deeply integrated with Google Cloud Platform.

You may submit your query as a Feature Request in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). However, for feature requests there is no guarantee of any time frame for updates or that the requested feature will be implemented.